# Linux setfacl options (-b,-x) differences

Tags: linux

What is the exact difference between  `-b` and `-x` option in the `Setfacl` command? are they the same? if not what is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

The `-x` option is short for `--remove` and it removes the *specified* ACL entries. For example:

```
setfacl -x u:httpd /home/Fred
```

The `-b` option is short for `--remove-all` which removes *all* ACL entries (leaving just the base "owner/group/other" which are non-removable).

```
setfacl -b /home/Fred
```

Comment: Thanks, one more question: if we have another user, for example, nginx, ACL also set for nginx user, after running -x for httpd the ACL remain for nginx ?